# PHP/Cookies: Working code with one condition, but trying to add a new one

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to make the page react differently if the url contains a predefined variable. My code is working fine with one variable "utm_source", but when I try to add another variable "fbclid" (only one at a time) it's not working. I'm not sure what is wrong with my code.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_setcookie' );
function my_setcookie() {
    if ( !isset( $_COOKIE['source'] )){
        setcookie( "source", $_GET['utm_source'], time() + 108000, "/", COOKIE_DOMAIN );
    }
    if ( !isset( $_COOKIE['fbsource'] )){
        setcookie( "fbsource", $_GET['fbclid'], time() + 108000, "/", COOKIE_DOMAIN );
    }
}

function strip_next_tags_action () { 
    global $post;
        if ( (!isset( $_GET['utm_source']) and !isset($_COOKIE['source'])) or (!isset( $_GET['fbclid']) and !isset($_COOKIE['fbsource']))) {
            $post->post_content = str_replace("<!--nextpage-->", "", $post->post_content, $count);
        }
        return $post;
    }
add_action ('loop_start', 'strip_next_tags_action');
```

I'm setting a cookie depending on the variable the url contains. Thank you

EDIT:
To clarify, when I said not working, the line:

```
$post->post_content = str_replace("<!--nextpage-->", "", $post->post_content, $count);
```

Is not working when the variable is fbclid

Comment: Is the cookie being set but not the desired value? or is it not being set at all? what issue are you having.

Comment: The issue is that the "!--nextpage--" is not replaced with "" when the variable is fbclid

Comment: what is the value of `$count` you are getting ?

Comment: When the variable fbclid is set it won't replace because you tell it not to

Comment: @Second2None when the fbclid is set it is not supposed to replace.

Comment: Ok just becaquse you said "The issue is that the "!--nextpage--" is not replaced with "" when the variable is fbclid" I assumed that you wanted it replaced when fbclid is present. $_COOKIE['source'] & $_COOKIE['fbsource'] will / should always be set, that means it will never execute because for that part of the code to run you require both parts of the AND to be not set.

Comment: I'm sorry. but as I said it's a logic problem for me and what you are telling me doesn't make sense. Maybe, if you can tweak my code to make it work I'll better understand. As for now, I can't see any problem in the code but it still won't work. Sorry again and thank you for your time

Comment: Where do you add the fbclid variable?

Comment: The fbclid is passed through the URL and stocked in a cookie